# Isometric offset and mouse positioning

Tags: java, 2d, game-engine, game-physics, isometric

I'm in the process of building a isometric framework so far I've got the physical tile mapping algorithm down.

[image: My Isometric map and how it auto maps the cell coordinates]

The thing is I don't want per tile collision, as in looping through all the tiles to check if my mouse is selecting a specific tile.
What I tried to accomplish is get cell index from the mouse using this.

```
int col = (int)(((double)mouse_x / (double)tileWidth) - ((double)mouse_y / (double)tileHeight) - 0.5);
int row = (int)(((double)mouse_y / (double)tileHeight) + ((double)mouse_x / (double)tileWidth) - 0.5);
```

But using this method my 0,15 is the 0,0 according to the mouse and the 0,0 is the 0,15.
So my question is how can I swap that around by editing the mouse code perhaps using offset?
Even so I wouldn't know how, so my question is how.

Answer (score 0):

I just went with the simple way out, instead of editing the initials equation.

I modified the outcome by:

```
    int col = (int)(((double)mouse_x / (double)tileWidth) - ((double)mouse_y / (double)tileHeight) - 0.5);
    int row = (int)(((double)mouse_y / (double)tileHeight) + ((double)mouse_x / (double)tileWidth) - 0.5);

    row = mapHeight - row - 1;
```

This flips the outcome, and thus fixes my problem in a non-artistic equational manner.

Answer (score 0):

From isometric coordinates to screen coordinates:

```
screenX = (isoX - isoY + isoMapMaxY) * (tileWidth / 2);
screenY = (isoX + isoY) * (tileHeight / 2);
```

From screen coordinates to isometric coordinates:

```
isoX = ( ((screenY + scrollY) / tileHeight) + ((screenX + scrollX) - (isoMapMaxY * tileWidth/2)) / tileWidth )
isoY = ( ((screenY + scrollY) / tileHeight) - ((screenX + scrollX) - (isoMapMaxY * tileWidth/2)) / tileWidth )

isoX = (screenY / 32) + (screenX - 320) / 64
isoY = (screenY / 32) - (screenX - 320) / 64
```